# How to instruct Vite to ignore (not bundle) the manifest I've already linked in index.html?

Tags: npm, build, vuejs3, vite, web-manifest

Could somebody tell me how I can instruct Vite to ignore the manifest I've already linked in index.html?

Vite is bundling my manifest and changing that line to

```
href="./assets/app-[hash].webmanifest"
```

I've tried everything, no way to set Vite for ignoring this link: <link rel="manifest"

Thank you.

I'm expecting Vite no changes to that line after executing 'npm run build'

PD:
I don't want to use the plugin 'vite-plugin-pwa'